# AWT Robot class Issue

Tags: java, keyboard, awtrobot

I'm here to talk to you about a problem I got today working for the first time whit this new class called "Robot" of the library java.awt.

I must say Robot works fine, but troubles come every time i stop the application. My keyboard doesn't recognize any command and when i try to write something, random Windows appear everywhere, 
as if the keyboard no longer recognizes the predefined keys. is there anyone who knows the reason for this strange behaviour and knows how to solve these issues?

thank you very much!

Comment: [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello, can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: and I was just trying to find out what AWL is.... Is it possible that you sent some *strange* commands or *unfinished* sequences to the keyboard (e.g. press ALT, but no released)?

Comment: If you're injecting key codes via Robot, you will need to remember to "release" the key as well as "press" it, this is especially important if you're using key combinations involving [Shift], [Alt], [Ctrl], [Command/Meta/Window]

Answer (score 0):

thankyou MadProgrammer, your observation was right! I solved my problem. 
I'm sorry I didn't provide an example related to my question but I was sure that someone would nave understood my problem.